# How to configure RDF4J Rio writer to write IRIs with special characters?

Tags: java, rdf4j

I want to write an `rdf4j.model.Model` with the `rdf/turtle` format. The model should contain IRIs with the characters `{}`.

When I try to write the RDF model with `rdf4j.rio.Rio`, the `{}` characters are written as `%7B%7D`. Is there a way to overcome this? e.g. create an `rdf4j.model.IRI` with [path and query variables](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570) or configure the writer to preserve the `{}` characters?

I am using `org.eclipse.rdf4j:rdf4j-runtime:3.6.2`.

An example snippet:

```
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.BNode;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.IRI;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Model;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.impl.SimpleValueFactory;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.util.ModelBuilder;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.*;
import org.eclipse.rdf4j.rio.helpers.BasicWriterSettings;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ExamplePathVariable {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ExamplePathVariable.class.getCanonicalName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleValueFactory rdf = SimpleValueFactory.getInstance();
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

        BNode subject = rdf.createBNode();
        IRI predicate = rdf.createIRI("http://example.org/onto#hasURI");

        // IRI with special characters !
        IRI object = rdf.createIRI("http://example.org/{token}");

        modelBuilder.add(subject, predicate, object);

        String turtleStr = writeToString(RDFFormat.TURTLE, modelBuilder.build());
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, turtleStr);
    }

    static String writeToString(RDFFormat format, Model model) {
        OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            Rio.write(model, out, format,
                    new WriterConfig().set(BasicWriterSettings.INLINE_BLANK_NODES, true));
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return out.toString();
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
INFO: 
[] <http://example.org/onto#hasURI> <http://example.org/%7Btoken%7D> .
```

Comment: I haven't got a clue what you're doing here, but I can tell you that the URI you've got there contains those curly braces encoded correctly, so they *are* being preserved probably.

Comment: Thanks, they are being preserved and there would not be an issue if the Rio parser could then treat %7B, %7D as {,} when reading a turtle file that contains `http://example.org/%7Btoken%7D` (at least in a closed application). But since this is not the case (at least without the knowledge of configuring the Rio parser for doing so), I'm still looking for a way for generating a .ttl file that actually shows the characters {,}. I could do the replacement manually, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way through rdf4j.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry if the question is not very clear. If there is more info I can give, I'll gladly do so. 
For example, on the [`NTriplesWriterSettings`](https://rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/org/eclipse/rdf4j/rio/helpers/NTriplesWriterSettings.html), there is an `ESCAPE_UNICODE` setting. But there is no such setting for the `TurtleWriter` nor the `BasicWriter`.

Comment: > if the Rio parser could then treat %7B, %7D as {,} when reading a turtle file<
 
Well how is that actually going, since the code above is just dumping what has been written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you want, because that would result in a syntactically invalid URI representation in Turtle.

The characters '{' and '}', even though they are not actually reserved characters in URIs, are not allowed to exist in un-encoded form in a URI (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3987). The only way to serialize them legally is by percent-encoding them.

As an aside the only reason this bit of code:

```java
IRI object = rdf.createIRI("http://example.org/{token}");
```

succeeds is that the `SimpleValueFactory` you are using does not do character validation (for performance reasons). If you instead use the [recommended approach](https://rdf4j.org/documentation/programming/model/#creating-new-building-blocks-the-values-and-statements-factory-methods) (since RDF4J 3.5) of using the `Values` static factory:

```java
IRI object = Values.iri("http://example.org/{token}");
```

...you would immediately have gotten a validation error.

If you want to input a string where in advance you don't know if it's going to contain any invalid chars, and want to have a best-effort approach to convert it to a legal URI, you can use `ParsedIRI.create`:

```java
IRI object = Values.iri(ParsedIRI.create("http://example.org/{token}").toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was genuinely confused because I was expecting that these characters do not need to be %-encoded since this is an IRI (and not just any URI). I should instead search for a library that supports URI templates.